# How to Make the Following CV template compile

Tags: compilation-error

I know how to use TeX, but I know nothing about coding. I am trying to write an academic CV for a conference application due tomorrow. At the following link, https://www.math.nyu.edu/student_resources/misc.php , under the header "CV TeX File" there is a CV template written in TeX and there is also a sample class file. The class file is needed to make the CV .TeX template compile, but I have no idea how I am supposed to do that; when I open the .TeX file in my TeX processor, I just get an error when I try to compile.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: People here don't follow external links. Please add the code here.

Comment: The code for the two files together goes over the total character limit. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: I don't mean the whole code. Try minimize that code and paste here a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), and you will get a higher chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't even know what means; I really know very little about code. Could you perhaps tell me what the purpose of a class file is? And how one uses a class file not to get an error?

Comment: You should begin with an introduction to LaTeX. Such documents explain the usage of document class and packages very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy the contents of [Sample CV Class File](https://www.math.nyu.edu/student_resources/res.cls) and put in a file named `res.cls`

And then compile your CV `Sample.tex` document. It should work.

I am sorry since I don't have enough reputations, I couldn't comment.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much, Naumar Afsar! It worked! I up-voted but have no reputation!

Comment: Well, I am glad that I could help ;). You can mark my answer as acceptable by clicking on that Tick!